# What is the number of $s-t$ cuts on $n$ vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to know why exactly the number of $s-t$ cuts (cuts that have $s$ in the tail and $t$ in the head) is $2^{n-2}$?

I tried to assume that $s$ has to be on the first set and $t$ has to be in the second set:

$=<\{s,.... \},\{t,.... \}>$

Then since the order is relevant, so we have to use permutation. And we have to fix $s$ and $t$, so could you please tell me to proceed from here to get the final answer $2^{n-2}$?

Comment: There is no ordering of vertices within a cut.

Comment: What is $n$, and what graph are you trying to count the $s-t$ cuts of?

Comment: @Joppy $n$ is stated to be the number of vertices, and the graph doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of the $n-2$ vertices *other* than $s$ and $t$, you have a choice between $2$ options: put the vertex in the first set or the second set. These choices are independent, giving $2^{n-2}$ total outcomes.